CSS how to select the first child only
<div class="item">
 <div><table>1</table></div>
  <div><table>2</table></div>
  <div><table>3</table></div>
</div>

I want to select the table which contains 1,below method doesn't work:
All the table will be applied, why?
item table:nth-child(1) {
xxxx
}
doesnt work.

Please make sure to give the actual attempt. item will not select anything. I suppose you did .item? Please review and correct.

Because table is always 1st inside its wrapping DIV, you should instead use .item div:nth-child(1) table { }

The selector item table:nth-child(1) doesn't work as expected because :nth-child() selects elements based on their position among siblings, not their overall position in the document structure.
In your case, each  is the first (and only) child of its parent , so all tables match :nth-child(1).
Final ans ->
.item > div:first-child table { xxxx }


You can try this:
.item div:first-child table {XXX}


"You can try this" is not really helpful as text. Please use text to explain what the problem was and how/why this corrects that problem.
